# Here i parse xml in java then making Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, layout

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ch17_05 extends DefaultHandler
{
    static int totalFigures = 0;
    static int x[] = new int[100];
    static int y[] = new int[100];
    static int width[] = new int[100];
        public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ch17_05 obj = new ch17_05();
        obj.childLoop("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\ch17_04.xml");

        AppFrame frame = new AppFrame(totalFigures, x, y, width);

        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {public void
            windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}});

        frame.show();
    }

    public void childLoop(String uri)
    {
        DefaultHandler defaultHandler = this;
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(new File(uri), defaultHandler);
        } catch (Throwable t) {}
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qualifiedName, Attributes attrs)
    {
        if (qualifiedName.equals("square")) {
            x[totalFigures] = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getValue("x"));
            y[totalFigures] = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getValue("y"));
            width[totalFigures] = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getValue("width"));
            totalFigures++; 
        }
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("Warning: " +
            exception.getMessage());
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " +
            exception.getMessage());
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("Fatal error: " +
            exception.getMessage());
    }
}

class AppFrame extends Frame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int totalFigures;
    int[] xValues;
    int[] yValues;
    int[] widthValues;

    public AppFrame(int number, int[] x, int[] y, int[] width)
        {


        totalFigures = number;
        xValues = x;
        yValues = y;
        widthValues = width;
        final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[totalFigures];
        for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < totalFigures; loopIndex++){
            //System.out.println("             "+xValues[loopIndex]);
            buttons[loopIndex] = new JButton(""+loopIndex);
            buttons[loopIndex].setBounds(xValues[loopIndex], yValues[loopIndex],widthValues[loopIndex], widthValues[loopIndex]);
            add(buttons[loopIndex]);
            System.out.println(xValues[loopIndex]);
        }

    }


   /* public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < totalFigures; loopIndex++){
            g.drawRect(xValues[loopIndex], yValues[loopIndex],
                widthValues[loopIndex], widthValues[loopIndex]);
              }
    }*/
}
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE document [
<!ELEMENT document (square)*>
<!ELEMENT square EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST square
    x CDATA #IMPLIED
    y CDATA #IMPLIED
    width CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<document>
    <square x='10' y='130' width='50' />
    <square x='140' y='180' width='15' />
</document>
```

The first button display correctly, the second button displays the entire frame.
Please give the answer for this as soon as possible.
Here I am parsing xml and making Jbutton in java.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Were did you encounter the problem and how does the result you get differ from the result you **should** be getting?

Answer (score 3):

1. You shouldn't be mixing Swing and AWT components like you're doing.  Instead make it all Swing components.
2. You shouldn't post a lot of code not relevant to your problem as you must remember that we're all volunteers. Instead post a minimal valid complete example, MVCE. For instance, the XML code is not needed, and instead you could simply post hard-coded numbers.
3. Please learn and follow Java naming conventions. Class names should begin with a capital letter, not lower case.
4. This is your homework, so you should do the brunt of the work. What have you done to debug the situation?
5. Avoid use of `setBounds(...)` with Swing GUI's since doing this causes you to create GUI's that are not flexible, that are not easily maintainable or upgradeable. Please start here: [Laying out Components within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/). For instance, you are adding JButtons directly to a Frame (again don't use Frames or other AWT components), and Frames use a BorderLayout. It looks like you want to use a GridLayout instead. If on the rare occasion you absolutely must use absolute positioning, the layout must be set to null, but this is a rare occurrence, indeed.
6. `"Please give the answer for this as soon as possible."` -- please leave these comments out. Remember we're volunteers and shouldn't be pushed or rushed. We'll get to your question as soon as is convenient for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

import org.xml.sax.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Ch17_05 extends DefaultHandler
{
    static int totalFigures = 0;
    static int x[] = new int[100];
    static int y[] = new int[100];
    static int width[] = new int[100];

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ch17_05 obj = new ch17_05();
        obj.childLoop("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\ch17_04.xml");

        AppFrame frame = new AppFrame(totalFigures, x, y, width);

        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {public void
            windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}});

        frame.show();
    }

    public void childLoop(String uri)
    {
        DefaultHandler defaultHandler = this;
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(new File(uri), defaultHandler);
        } catch (Throwable t) {}
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qualifiedName, Attributes attrs)
    {
        if (qualifiedName.equals("square")) {
            x[totalFigures] = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getValue("x"));
            y[totalFigures] = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getValue("y"));
            width[totalFigures] = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getValue("width"));
            totalFigures++; 
        }
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("Warning: " +
            exception.getMessage());
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " +
            exception.getMessage());
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("Fatal error: " +
            exception.getMessage());
    }
}

class AppFrame extends Frame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int totalFigures;
    int[] xValues;
    int[] yValues;
    int[] widthValues;
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    public AppFrame(int number, int[] x, int[] y, int[] width)
        {

        add(content);
        content.setLayout(null);
        totalFigures = number;
        xValues = x;
        yValues = y;
        widthValues = width;
        final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[totalFigures];
        for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < totalFigures; loopIndex++){
            //System.out.println("             "+xValues[loopIndex]);
            buttons[loopIndex] = new JButton(""+loopIndex);
            buttons[loopIndex].setBounds(xValues[loopIndex], yValues[loopIndex],widthValues[loopIndex], widthValues[loopIndex]);
            content.add(buttons[loopIndex]);
            System.out.println(xValues[loopIndex]);
        }

    }


   /* public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < totalFigures; loopIndex++){
            g.drawRect(xValues[loopIndex], yValues[loopIndex],
                widthValues[loopIndex], widthValues[loopIndex]);
              }
    }*/
}
```